# How to create a very simple username - password login in PHP?

Tags: php, session, authentication, session-cookies

index.php

```
<?php
if( $_SESSION['auth'] != 1 ) {
    require( 'login.php' );
}
else {
    echo "hello";
}
?>
```

login.php

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

if( isset($name) || isset($pass) )
{
    if( empty($name) ) {
        die ("ERROR: Please enter username!");
    }
    if( empty($pass) ) {
        die ("ERROR: Please enter password!");
    }


    if( $name == "<some name>" && $pass == "<some password>" )
    {
        // Authentication successful - Set session
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['auth'] = 1;
        setcookie("username", $_POST['name'], time()+(84600*30));
        echo "Access granted!";
    }
    else {
        echo "ERROR: Incorrect username or password!";
    }
}


// If no submission, display login form
else {
?>
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <center>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    Username: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $_COOKIE['username']; ?>">
    <p />
    Password: <input type="password" name="pass">
    <p />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In">
    </center>
    </body>
    </html>
<?php
}
?>
```

So, as I'm still learning PHP, there's a few things I'm trying to figure out now:

- How do I get it so I can reload index.php and it displays 'hello'?
- How can I get login.php to auto-load index.php on a successful authentication so I can get it to that "hello"?
- Later, would using a cookie to store the user's submitted login data (so they don't have to refill the form to restore their session) have any potential problems?

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1, You're missing session_start() in index.php. Add it and you should be able to see 'Hello world'

2, Replace your line with "Access granted!" with a redirect:

```
header('Location: index.php');
exit;
```

3, You can definitely store credentials in a cookie, but you should always hash and salt the password. [Here](http://phpsec.org/articles/2005/password-hashing.html) is a good article about password hashing.

Answer (score 4):

Better way of doing things:
Check for the session variable in the index.php and redirect if it is not set. Something like this

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['auth']) || $_SESSION['auth'] != 1) {
   header('Location: login.php');
   exit();
}
echo 'Hello';
```

In the login.php, after successful authentication, redirect to index.php and do the echo there.

```
session_start();
if( $name == "<some name>" && $pass == "<some password>" )
{
// Authentication successful - Set session
   $_SESSION['auth'] = 1;
   setcookie("username", $_POST['name'], time()+(84600*30));
   header('Location: index.php');
   exit();
}
else {
  echo "ERROR: Incorrect username or password!";
}
```

session_start() should come before any content is echoed to the browser.

Answer (score 2):

You should:

1. always try to call **[`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)** as early as possible - *"To use cookie-based sessions, `session_start()` must be called before outputing anything to the browser."*
2. check whether `$_POST['name']` isset before doing `$name = $_POST['name'];`. You can do:

   ```
   $name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
   ```
3. store the `username` directly in `$_SESSION` so that cookie holds only `PHPSESSID` and no data that could be replaced / abused by the end users:

   ```
   $_SESSION['user'] = 'John';
   ```
4. try to redirect the user to `index.php` to see the immediate result of changing the session:

   ```
   header('Location: index.php');
   exit;
   ```

So this is how it could look like:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION['user'])) {

    $name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
    $pass = isset($_POST['pass']) ? $_POST['pass'] : '';

    if ($name != '' || $pass != '')
    {
        if ($name === '')
            die("ERROR: Please enter the username!");

        if ($pass === '')
            die("ERROR: Please enter the password!");

        if ($name == "test" && $pass == "test") {

            // authentication successful, save username in session:
            $_SESSION['user'] = 'John';

            // redirect to index.php to welcome the logged in user:
            header('Location: index.php');
            exit;
        }
        else {
            die("ERROR: Incorrect username or password!");
        }
    }

    // no submitted data, display form:
    ?>
        <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
            <center>
            <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
            Username: <input type="text" name="name" value=""><br>
            Password: <input type="password" name="pass"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Log In">
            </form>
            </center>
        </body>
        </html>
    <?php
}
else {
    // info about current user is stored in session, welcome this user:
    echo "hello " . $_SESSION['user'];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

> How do I get it so I can reload index.php and it displays 'hello'?

Remove the `else`, so it will always display the "hello":

```
if($_SESSION['auth'] != 1) {
    require('login.php');
}
// Either way always print.
echo "hello";
```

> How can I get login.php to auto-load index.php on a successful authentication so I can get it to that "hello"?

Replace `echo "Access granted!";` with `header('Location:index.php');`

> Later, would using a cookie to store the user's submitted login data (so they don't have to refill the form to restore their session) have any potential problems?

As long as are using this as a way to autofill the username only. and require the users to enter their password every time. otherwise a user can set his username cookie to "admin" or some other user.

Comment: I meant display 'hello' after successful authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to redirect to index.php (I hope it answers your #1 and #2)

```
if( $name == "<some name>" && $pass == "<some password>" )
{
    // Authentication successful - Set session
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['auth'] = 1;
    setcookie("username", $_POST['name'], time()+(84600*30));
    //echo "Access granted!";
    header("Location: index.php");
    die('');
}
```

You are using cookies to store the username directly. That is not a great option. What if a user modifies the cookies, to read some other username? Instead use `$_SESSION['..']`
Like this:

```
$_SESSION['user']=$_POST['name'];
```

and then later on,

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user']))
    echo "Hello, " . $_SESSION['user'];
```

Answer (score 0):

no one is mentioning that you should check that the session is actually a valid one... if you just check it's set you can most likley fake it and get through.
also to hash credentials into the cookie i would encrypt it first server side and then hash it. just in case somewhere in the future someone breaks the hash type. sha3-256 is your best choice here as it's not known to be broken and should resist alot of computing power increase in the future.

What i usually do is to encrypt password and user with the user password itself as key, that way, if you also store their credentials in this fasion in your own database, there is no way even for the site maintainer to decrypt it and steal the passwords. and any db dumping skiddie will have only some meta data. (you should also encrypt the usernames...)

It seems a little conveluted to be a 'simple login and password for the users' but really as simple as possible should still consider security for your users, even if it's not a public site...

So remember:

- check sessions and cookies for valid contents if they are there
- check user and pw input fields for sane data before forwarding to your auth process.
- encrypt user and pw information in your server side, and in the client side if you send it there (cookies?).
- use AES256 atleast (mysql support this native since 5.6 its really easy to use...) for encrypting data.
- use sha3-256 for hashing.
- look at guides for crypto and hashing as it's easy to mess up.
- ask a friend in the know to test your setup to best of their ability for a crate of beer ^^ and have fun with him and learn a bunch of stuff about your code :D

  - lastly, i will have forgotten (or don't know atall) alot of stuff, so there will be missing bullets! :D